# NoMethodError (undefined method `silence' for #<GELF::Logger:0x000055c41ec5abd8>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graylog

versions :-
rails 6.0.0
ruby 2.6.6

this is my code in application.rb

```
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Graylog2.new

config.logger = GELF::Logger.new(
  "127.0.0.1",
  "12201",
  'WAN',
  facility: "MY APP",
  host: "LOCAL",
 )
```

i ran my rails application in production mode and I'm getting this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `silence' for #<GELF::Logger:0x000055c41ec5abd8>)
```

Comment: Maybe add the full stack trace as well as some code showing where the error occurs if possible? Right now all we can tell you is that `#silence` is not an instance method of `GELF::Logger` because that is what the error states.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was discussed on github. Check out:

https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/issues/176

Probably you updated some gems and ran into this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).